# How to find all possible indices of an array

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

Supposing we have an array with this shape: `[2, 5]`. The possible index combinations are:

```
[
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [0, 3],
  [0, 4],
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4]
]
```

If the array has `n` dimension(s), is there a simple way to generate the indices in Ruby?

Comment: There should be more combinations.. How is this only ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit No there shouldn't, it's 2x5 so there are 10 index combos.

Comment: @pjs what are the actual elements? why only this came? "possible combinations " means what.. the example doesn't make sense. I am not talking about *10 index combos*.. I am telling how do you select the elements from all the possible combinations? Please do this `a = (0..4)
p a.to_a.combination(2).to_a` and check how many combinations are possible ?

Comment: If n is fixed, use nested loops.  If n is variable, use recursion.

Comment: @ArupRakshit It doesn't matter what the element values are, Doug appears to be asking for the indices.

Comment: @pjs any of the first `10` will be good?

Comment: I confirm I would like to generate every index combos, as @pjs said, from a given matrix's shape. My question was not very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
def coordinates(first, *others)
  (0...first).to_a.product(*others.map { |to| (0...to).to_a })
end

coordinates(2, 5)
#=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4],
#    [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]

coordinates(4, 3, 3)
#=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2],
#    [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2],
#    [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2],
#    [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2],
#    [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2],
#    [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
#    [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2],
#    [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2],
#    [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2],
#    [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 2],
#    [3, 1, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 2],
#    [3, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: Much nicer than my solution. Kudos!

Comment: Very short and nice! Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  It may not be pretty, but it seems to work.

```
def gen_indices(dimensions, solutions = [], current=[], level = 0)
  if level < dimensions.length
    dimensions[level].times do |i|
      current << i
      if level == dimensions.length - 1
        solutions << current.clone
      else
        gen_indices(dimensions, solutions, current, level + 1)
      end
      current.pop
    end
  end
  solutions
end

p gen_indices([4,3,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is totally correct, but it should help you on the right track:

```
def combinations(dimensions)
  dimensions.inject([]){|total, dimension|
    dim = (0...dimension).to_a
    total.empty? ? dim : total.product(dim)
  }.map(&:flatten)
end

p combinations([2, 5]) #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]


p combinations([2, 2, 2]) #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a = [[0,1],[0,1,2,3,4]]
res = a[0].product(a[1])
```